# noob question: how do I add the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE from within a python script?

Tags: python, django, django-settings

Apologies for a basic question but I honestly haven't found an actionable answer yet even though I'm sure this is a simple solve.

I'm calling a python file which is part of a Django app (same folder as the models, views etc) from the command line, from a totally different working directory. The python file is called as a module and not as a package since I'm not using the "-m" argument. The python file imports from the models file, upon which I get a long Traceback through the **init** files etc ending in the below error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

So I'm adding the following line in the python file before the `from models import modelA, modelB` statement:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', "C:/Users/oktested/further_file_path/settings")
```

Basically I'm putting the entire path to the settings.py file in there, without the .py extension. But upon doing this I get a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'C:\Users\oktested\'`.

How do I express the path to the settings.py file that already exists in my Django project? I am using Django 2.1 on Windows 10 FYI.

Update with the project file structure:

```
project1/
  db
  manage.py
  MyAppFolder/
      __init__.py
      models.py
      views.py
      script.py
  project1folder/
      settings.py
      __init__.py
```

script.py is the file that I need to call from outside, and settings.py is the settings file. In manage.py, the django_settings_module is easily declared as 'project1folder.settings' since it is in the same directory as manage.py. How do I declare the django_settings_module in script.py so that script.py can continue to behave normally as if I called it from within my Django app?

Comment: The line should be something like `os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', "oktested.settings")`. You haven’t showed your project layout or the location of the script so we can’t guve the actual value.

Comment: But it's probably simpler to write your standalone script as a [Django management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-management-commands/), which avoids this whole issue.

Comment: @Alasdair - I updated the question with the project layout and script location. Hope this helps. Kindly note that I'm calling the script from a totally unconnected directory in another path altogether, so 'projectfolder1.settings' will result in `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named projectfolder1`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks for your reply! I am calling the script from the command line (outside Django) as a file, and not from another Django project. Will writing a Django-admin management command help me write script that behaves just as if it is part of the Django app? It should be able to freely import functions from the other modules of the app and then make database edits etc.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what it does. You would run it as `manage.py myscript`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I've created a management command under `MyAppFolder/management/commnds/myscript.py` How should I make Django register a command inside manage.py for this script? Currently I don't see any change inside manage.py. Much appreciated.

Comment: I just needed to create __init__.py files inside each directory and it helped register the custom command. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use the command:

`python manage.py shell`

Suppose you want to call the "foo" function in the views.py file.

You may write in the prompt:

`>> from myapp.views import foo`

`>>foo()`

Comment: Thanks for the reply but sadly I am unable to do that. The call from cmd is outside my control. Whatever I do has to be inside the script. It needs to behave just as if it has been called from within the app (which already works fine), and as if the imports (models) are being made from within the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert the path to the django project into `sys.path`, e.g. on Windows:

```
sys.path.insert(1, r'C:\your\path\djangoproject')
```

From there, you can specify the dotted path to the settings file, e.g.:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "yourapp.settings")
django.setup()
```

Comment: I got the below error:
Traceback:
`File "C:\filepath\MyAppFolder\script.py", line 16, in <module> from models import Customer, Shops, Purchases`

`File "C:\filepath\MyAppFolder\models.py", line 3, in <module> from django.contrib.auth.models import User`

`File "C:\anotherfilepath\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 2, in <module> from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager`

`File "C:\anotherfilepath\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 47, in <module> class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):`

<to be continued below>

Comment: <continued from above>
  File "C:\anotherfilepath\django\db\models\base.py", line 87, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "C:\anotherfilepath\django\apps\registry.py", line 249, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "C:\anotherfilepath\django\apps\registry.py", line 132, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")

django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.

Comment: Basically I'm getting a `django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.` error

Comment: You need `django.setup()` after importing the settings.

Comment: BTW, additional error or code printouts belong into your question which you can [edit here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55276202/edit).

Comment: Thanks @Endre ! I was under the impression that django.setup() is only for use in stand-alone scripts. Anyway, I tried it, but I got this error "django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty." I already have the SECRET_KEY in my settings file.

Comment: If you are working in a barebones interpreter, doesn't that qualify as standalone? You should be able to access the settings with e.g. `from django.conf import settings; settings.SECRET_KEY`. Does this work?